# Remove Xamarin Debug Settings In iOS App Settings

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Is Visual Studios for MacOS, I'm trying to prevent the Xamarin Debug Settings from showing up when the app is installed from TestFlight. Settings -> App Name -> Debug Settings

[image]

I'm selecting Release and Generic Device before archiving.
[image]

Within Options I also have debug disabled for the release configuration.
[image]

What other settings am I missing to prevent this from showing up under my app's settings?

Comment: I noticed that you have turned off the Enable debugging option. Can you still use debug?

Comment: @Tsukasa, Did you got any solution for this , kindly share if you found any. I also have the same issue.